# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Hey everyone I'm in intro python programming and we're doing out first independent code. The assignment is as follows:

> Prompt the user for his or her name. Then prompt the user for two numbers and then perform a mathematical operation of your choice on them.  Make sure the program works with decimal numbers, and that you print a full equation in response, not just the result:
>   Enter a number: 2.3
>   Enter another number: 3.6
>   2.3 – 3.6 = -1.3

So I entered:

```
def main1():
print("This is program 1!")
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
print("Pleased to meet you,", name ,"!") #next line def main2():
print("This is program 2!")
import math
number = input("Enter a number: ")
number = float(number)
numberr = input("Enter another number: ")
numberr = float(numberr)
print = ("number + numberr")
```

And I keep on getting this:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment
```

Help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python variable scope error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error)

Comment: There are a _lot_ of duplicates for `UnboundLocalError` on Stack Overflow.  The right side of your screen should show at least ten of them.

Answer (score 4):

You try to assign a value to `print`.

You wrote:

```
print = ("number + numberr")
```

But you in fact meant:

```
print(number + numberr)
```

Comment: I'll add, you'd have an easier time finding what your problem is (and getting help from others when encountering an exception) if you read/post the full traceback starting from "Traceback".  Tracebacks tell you what line of code your problem is on.